# Heroku worker dyno produces file, how to read it from web dyno?

Tags: heroku, delayed-job

When asked by the admin, my Heroku worker generates a report, compressed as a ~10MB ZIP file.

Generation takes about one minute, so it is done by `delayed_job`.
Once generation is done, where to store the file so that the web dyno can serve it?

- `tmp` folder is not the same from one dyno to another, it seems.
- Free database (5MB) is not large enough to contain the 10MB file

Is there no option besides storing the file in the database and paying to switch from 5MB to 20GB database?

*Note: There is only one admin, and generating the report is a rare event.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about just uploading the file onto Amazon S3 and having it accessed from there?

Comment: Great idea! Looks like Heroku is not for file storage indeed.

Comment: no, If you think of Heroku as a read only file system then you'll be good. Whilst certain areas of various stacks are writable (eg tmp) NONE of them persist across dynos or restarts.